# Error using mex LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'ifconsol.lib'

Tags: matlab, visual-c++, compiler-errors, lib, intel-composer

In MATLAB 2015a, When I use the `mex -output` command with some parameter, I get this error:

> Building with 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 Professional'.
>   Error using mex 
>   LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'ifconsol.lib'

I know that this error is related to Intel Composer XE 2013, but I don't know how I can solve it. As you see there is some `ifconsol.lib` in Intel Composer XE 2013 folders:

[image]

Comment: Hi, I'm having a very hard time getting my head around the problem here. Can you add the code you used when this error happened. Also, have you tried finding some documentation on the XE compiler in combination with Matlab? I'm pretty sure that there's some docs on how to set up the compiler.

Comment: I've never worked with Intel Compilers before, so correct me if I'm wrong here. But it seems strange to me that you get an error from the Microsoft Visual C++ compiler if you're trying to use the Intel Composer XE compiler...Have you run `mex -setup`?